# Chapter title with specific number

Tags: numbering, chapters

I was wondering how I would get the number 9 to appear on my chapter in latex?

so far for my title code i have

```
\documentclass{report}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Polarity,\\ and blocking and \\anti-blocking polyhedra
}

\end{document}
```

[image: Picture Link]

Comment: `\setcounter{chapter}{8}` before your `\chapter{Polarity}` should do... note, it's `8`, since `\chapter` increases the chapter number itself and it will have the value of `9` then. By the way: The `\\\` inside of the `\chapter` title does not look very well.

Comment: Comment aside: If you plan to have a separate chapter with exactly this number, the `\setcounter{...}` approach is correct, but normally I would expect you to have 8 chapters before or a strange resetting/manipulation of the chapter counter before occurs.

Comment: I am pretty sure this is a dupe, but I did not found one (with a quick search)

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass{report}

\setcounter{chapter}{8}
\renewcommand{\chaptername}{}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{Polarity, and blocking and anti-blocking polyhedra}

\end{document}
```

[image]